# Recover permanently deleted files from recyle bin

Tags: windows, data-recovery

By mistake, I have empty my recycle bin. I want a file back which was in Recycle bin. Is there any method to restore the file again which was deleted from recycle bin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Just you have to know the location of the file previously before deleting for example: File named A was in D Drive i folder B so:---

1: Right click on the folder in which the file was kept before deletion.
2: And select restore previous versions and then select the date

Boom files back